# How to put a large gif into github repository readme file?

Tags: git, github, markdown, readme

I need to add a gif to a readme file in my repository, but the size of the gif extends 25mb that is the maximal possible filesize for a file a repository. So I cannot store the gif in the repository. Where can I store the gif for the markdown file? Or is it impossible to add a large gif to the readme file?

Comment: \>25Mb is an outrageously excessive filesize for a readme gif. Shrink it first!

Comment: For a single GIF, you’re probably best off referencing this from an existing website without storing it in git, [as Greg suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62875740/3025856). If you want this file to be versioned, and/or will have multiple files like this, you might want to investigate the [Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store/host it remotely and reference it from the readme file using `<img src="...">` or md syntax.